# IBM RSA: Code Generation out of which diagram types?

Tags: code-generation, uml

**Can only Class Diagrams be transformed? 

Or can other diagram types be put to good use, too?**

For a university project we are forced to put the Rational Software Architect to good use.

I was not able to find reliable information on that topic by myself for hours, that is why I am asking here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code generation is only from class diagram.

If you export your model to xmi serialization then after a long and painful job you could be able to generate code but this code generation is not integrated in the tool.

Comment: It is possible to access the RSA model right inside the Eclipse VM with a plugin. No need to bother with xmi serialization. And if you really like to use the xmi file Eclipse uml2 tools can already load it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box RSA generates code for Classes and Associations etc., if you have a version/cartridge supporting that.

But RSA uses the org.eclipse.uml model, which is EMF based. This means you can use any generator like XPand or JET to generate custom code for any UML model element.

Comment: Agreed.  There's a vibrant community around transformation and generation from emf based models - take a look at eclipse modeling (www.eclipse.org/modeling), especially model-to-text (www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/) and model-to-model (www.eclipse.org/m2m/).  There's much more scope to generate the code you want using these tools than the RSA built in stuff.  Note also that XPand has been largely replaced by xtend2 (http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/). hth.